# Laravel permission get user roles as object instead of array

Tags: eloquent, roles, laravel-permission

Currently using spatie/laravel-permission package to manage user roles: an user could have a single role.

```
return $this->userModel
    ->select('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'slug')
    ->with(['roles' => function ($query) {
        $query->select('name', 'guard_name');
    }])
    ->find($id);
```

Hoever, when I'm running the following query, it returns an array of roles.

```
"roles": [
    {
        "name": "personal_trainer",
        "pivot": {
            "model_id": "9e8fb1a1-e725-4b48-befa-d9c4783c9eda",
            "role_id": 2,
            "model_type": "App\\Models\\User\\User"
        }
    }
],
```

How can I make "roles" key return a single object instead of an array? I want to avoid manipulating it post-query.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try

```
return $this->userModel
    ->select('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'slug')
    ->with(['roles' => function ($query) {
        $query->select('name', 'guard_name');
    }])
    ->first();
```

Comment: I already do this but I forgot to mention

Comment: Related models always return an array. You will have to modify the return array to get what you want.